# Handling large files on a server with PHP

Tags: php

I have had my shared web server suspended twice now for moving large files with a self-built php CMS using copy(). The admins told me that I had used up all the read/write bandwidth on the machine and that PHP is very inefficient at moving files.

I want to be able to move these files via a web interface in my CMS. Is there a way I can do this without bogging down the server?

Comment: Again and again. Why the downvote! At least put a reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to move them, use [`rename()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

Since you're doing this from a CMS, are you using user input to determine source or destination?  Be sure to sanitize any inputs, one thing to look at is [`realpath()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use [rename](http://php.net/rename). This will just change the place in the filesystem, not copy the entire contents of the file, and therefore is much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, this does make more sense. I'm not sure why this did not cross my mind.